# Generator density in $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$

Tags: pr.probability, nt.number-theory

Hello,

Consider the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^*$ for a given prime $p$. We know that the number of generators in this group is $\phi(p-1)$ --- the Euleur totient function. The question is, for $0 \leq a < a + \log^{c} p < b \leq p-1$ where $c$ is a constant (say $c=10$), how many generators of the group belongs to $[a,b]$? In other words, what is the density of generators in a given interval $[a,b]$ (compared to the density $\phi(p-1)/p-1$)? Is it easier if $b=p-1$?

For a given prime $p$, what is the densest interval in term of generators?

Comment: As far as I am aware, the shortest intervals known to include at least *one* generator have length $O((\log p)^2)$, assuming the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis. Unconditionally, you can’t even get anywhere near that. Thus, I doubt you can get any nontrivial answer.

Comment: No, sorry, this bound was for quadratic nonresidues. For generators, it is $O((\log p)^6)$, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: just added the number theory tag

Comment: It is standard for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to refer to $p$ adic number. You want the quotient by the prime ideal.

Comment: It is standard for ${\bf Z}_p$ to refer to whatever the person using it says it refers to. The usage in this question was perfectly clear and not in any need of editing. 

Comment: I have just relaxed the length of $[a,b]$, the length can be lower-bounded by $(\log p)^c$ for some small constant $c$. Is there any nontrivial answer?

Comment: Suppose $x$ is some parameter and $p$ is a large prime much larger than $x$. (It might be better if $p-1$ is squarefree to minimize the ratio between $p-1$ and its radical.) If one would actually know the density of numbers relatively prime to $p-1$ in a short range, say of size $x$, then one can estimate the set of numbers less than $x$ relatively prime to all primes dividing $p-1$ without using inclusion-exclusion. With inclusion-exclusion, one would get a $O(2^{\omega(p-1)})$ term, so it seems this would allow one to circumvent that.


Comment: More rigorously, suppose that $x$ is of size about $(\log p)^c$. If the radical of $p-1$ is the product of all primes up to $z$ (it is definitely an unsolved problem whether there are infinitely many such primes $p$), and if $p-1$ is equal to its radical (then $p$ is a primorial prime and this is even harder), then $p$ is of size about $e^{z/\log z}$ and $x$ is about $(z/\log z)^c$. Using inclusion-exclusion one gets an error of $2^{x^{1/c}}$.


Comment: A fairly standard character sum technique leads to the conclusion that the
number of primitive roots mod $p$ in an interval of length $Q$ is
$$ \frac{\phi(p-1)}{p-1)}\,\big(Q+2^{k+1}\theta\sqrt p\log p\big), $$ where
$k$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $p-1$ and $|\theta|<1$ (see
Vinogradov's "Elements of Number Theory", Chapter VI, Problem 14-b-$\beta$).
I hardly believe there are any substantial improvements known.